# animation nodes with follow path object contraint not possible?

Tags: animation-nodes

Is there a restriction with animation nodes and follow path constraints?

I have made a sphere which distance to the single plane controls the angles of the underlying plane grid. Works great. If i move around the sphere the planes turn accordingly.

Now i wanted to animate the sphere by a curve (because i am to lazy to keyframe it) and i added a curve and added the object constraint "follow path" to it. Now i keyframe the offset 0 to 100 at the beginning and the end of my animation.

Unfortunately now animation nodes does not react anymore to the movement of the sphere.

If i move the sphere manually in 3d view it works like a charm.

what am i missing?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow path animation can be done inside AN without any constraints.

[image]

Comment: great, thank you, works perfectly.